# Share a file between solutions, “Add as Link” do not work as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created common UI.css file and would like to share it between several projects. I have put it into separated folder and linked it using Existing Item... -> “Add as Link”. The file appears in solution explorer window as file with shortcut icon and I can open that file for editing with double click. The problem is that file is not copied to project and I can't use insert it into asp.net master template as

```
<link href="styles/ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I get error that file is not found. How to share css file between projects?

Comment: Set the 'Copy to Output directory' property of the file UI.css to 'Copy Always'?

Comment: @GarethOwen That is not working.  I see only file shortcut in solution explorer and no logical file on disc in project folder.

Answer (score 2):

Add as link does just as it suggests, simply adds a link to the file to the project file without actually making a copy of the file and moving it to the directory, so your code above will never work.

In terms of actually achieving this, perhaps if both of your sites are in the same solution you could add the css file to the solution as a solution file, I'm not 100% sure where these get put but you should be able to reference them the same way from either web site.

see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kz72ax7.aspx) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ee8zw5t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: No, my projects are not in the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

To overcome this problem some time ago I created a '[MSBuild.WebApplication.CopyContentLinkedFiles](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.WebApplication.CopyContentLinkedFiles/)' nuget package. This package adds MsBuild target which copies all content files added as link to project folder during build.